# Central extensions of elementary abelian p-groups

Tags: finite-groups, group-cohomology, group-extensions

Given an elementary abelian $p$-group $E$, we can consider $E$ as a trivial $E$-module; my first question is :

How can one compute  the rank of of the cohomology group $\operatorname{H}^n(E,E)$, $n \geq 2$?

I'm essentially interested to $\operatorname{H}^2(E,E)$.

Let $G$ be an extension of $E$ by $E$.  How much it is difficult to classify all such groups $G$ having the property $\Omega_1(G)=G^p$?  Is it true that every such a group is abelian (so homocyclic of exponent $p^2$) if $p$ is odd.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, $G=\langle a,b : a^{p^2} = b^{p^2}=1, b^a = b^{1+p} \rangle$ has $\Omega_1(G)=G^p$ is central elementary abelian with isomorphic elementary abelian quotient.

Comment: @Jack Schmidt : Yes.  What do you think about an attempt to classify them?

Comment: I'm not sure. It looks like none of order p^2, one of order p^4, 2p+9 of order p^6 (+2 if p=2). All of these examples satisfy $\Omega_1(G) \leq Z(G)$, and such groups have a more restricted structure. If $E=\Omega_1(G)$, then we are in that case, but I'm not even sure that happens in general.

Comment: One can try Kunneth formula for such computations, I am not sure, however, how messy the answer will be for the general $n$. But the case $n=2$ is quite doable since $H^1$ and $H^0$ are both clear.